# C++ accessing object on heap after end of pointer scope

Tags: c++, pointers, scope, heap-memory

I've been reading various questions and answers about pointers in C++ on SO but I still am fundamentally not understanding something.

I've read that pointers allow for dynamic memory allocation, by not actually deleting an object until explicitly told to do so. This I understand, but what I don't understand is how an object on the heap is ever referred to again after the scope of its pointer ends.

See code below.

```
{
   myClass* x = new myClass();
}
// How to access the object that x points to here?
```

I understand that at the end of the scope, `x` (the pointer itself) no longer exists, but the object (that the pointer was pointing to) still does exist on the heap.

My question is: How is that address in memory ever accessed again if the pointer that points to that address in memory no longer exists?

Comment: It isn't.  This is called a memory leak.

Comment: Then how is it possible to access this address outside of this scope? I thought that was the entire point of dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: This is why it is preferable to use smart pointers

Comment: @Peter You have to pass the pointer of the scope somehow.  The memory will live on but if you don't store that address somewhere you're not going to be able to access it again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How is that address in memory ever accessed again if the pointer that points to that address in memory no longer exists?

If the pointer value is not stored elsewhere, the object is "leaked" and becomes inaccessible.  The object will continue to exist until the process terminates, at which point the operating system will reclaim the memory used by the object.

> what I don't understand is how an object on the heap is ever referred to again after the scope of its pointer ends.

The pointer would have to be copied somewhere else.  For example, you might put the pointer into a vector or a map before the local pointer goes out of scope, and then the object can still be accessed through the pointer stored in the vector/map:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<myClass *> objects;

    {
        myClass *x = new myClass();
        objects.push_back(x);
    }

    // The heap-allocated object can be accessed through objects[0] now
    objects[0]->doSomething();

    // Don't forget to clean up (or use smart pointers)
    for (auto i : objects) { delete i; }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Note that it's useful to learn how to use raw pointers when learning C++, but at some point you should switch to smart pointers like [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), which will automatically `delete` the pointed-to object for you:

```
{
    std::unique_ptr<myClass> x{new myClass()};
}
// The myClass object has already been deleted by the smart pointer
```

Comment: "...useful to learn how to use raw pointers when learning C++...": Actually, if I were teaching C++ to beginners, I would probably never mention raw `new`/`delete` at all until a very advanced level of the classes, and even defer smart pointers and "observer pointers" until there's an actual need for them (e.g. vector of polymorphic objects, custom recursive data structure).  Best to get students into the habit of putting containers directly as members of classes, rather than doing unnecessary dynamic allocations.

Comment: @cdhowie Thanks for the explanation. Just to clarify,in this example, if `std::unique_ptr<myClass> x{new myClass()};` was used, then later in your code `objects[0]` would have given an error, since the smart pointer would have already deleted that object when the scope ended, correct?

Comment: @Peter Right, but instead you should use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<myClass>>`. Then you can *move-construct* the `unique_ptr` in the vector, which will transfer ownership from the local `x`. Then `x` will point to `nullptr`, and `objects[0]` will own the allocation. When the vector is destroyed, it will destroy all of the `unique_ptr` objects it contains, which will in turn destroy the `myClass` objects.

Comment: One more clarification: My understanding is that inside of the local scope in the example above, both `x` and `objects[0]` were basically two ways to access the same object, and outside of the scope, `objects[0]` was the only way to access the object because `x` no longer exists. However, you're saying that if `objects` is a smart pointer, then after the line of code `objects.pushback(x)`, then `x` is automatically changed to `nullptr`?

Comment: @Peter Correct. Only one `unique_ptr` can "own" the same object at any given time. Constructing a second `unique_ptr` from the first *transfers ownership* to the second, and the first one is reset to point nowhere. If you want a shared-ownership smart pointer, then use `shared_ptr` instead.

Comment: That makes sense. This is why I've read that plain objects should be preferred over `unique_ptr` which should be preferred over `shared_ptr` which should be preferred over raw pointers. Each level allows more flexibility but also allows more things to go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a small example that shows the differences between (1) allocation without proper deletion, (2) allocation with proper deletion, and (3) allocation using a smart pointer that deletes itself when it goes out of scope. Just run the program to see that the first example leaks memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class A
{
    public:
        A(std::string name) : name_(name) 
        {
            std::cout << "My name is " << name_ << ", and I make mess...\n";
        }
        ~A()
        {
            std::cout << "My name is " << name_ << ", and I clean up...\n";
        }
    private:
        std::string name_;
};

int main()
{
    // 1. Leaks.
    A* a0;
    a0 = new A("a0");

    // 2. Does not leak.
    A* a1;
    a1 = new A("a1");
    delete a1;

    // 3. Does not leak.
    std::unique_ptr<A> a2 = std::make_unique<A>("a2");

    return 0;
}
```